# Ordering non-numeric tuples by total value (distance?) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, ord

EDIT: I just realized that this won't solve the problem at all, except for lists with every entry in the set (i.e. getting a comparative value for `(a,e)` and `(b,d)` won't help me at all if the list doesn't contain e, but does contain f). Derp. That said, the question of distance comparisons for ordered but non-numeric sets in Haskell is still IMO interesting, so...

I have to write a function

```
pairs :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,a)]
```

which returns all pairs (x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>j</sub>) from a list where x<sub>i</sub> < x<sub>j</sub> and i < j.

That's pretty straightforward with list comprehensions. Now, I need it sorted, and I need it sorted by the "order" of the tuples. That is, the combined order - (a,z) needs to come a long way after (b,c). For integers, this is easy - add x<sub>i</sub> to x<sub>j</sub> and use that for the comparison.

However, this is over `Ord`, so this function has to take obnoxious things like chars, and in Haskell, all I know how to get is `GT`, `LT`, or `EQ` - not how much `GT`. Is there a way to get Haskell to say

> `Z` is 25 Greater Than `A`

or something like that? Or any other ideas on how to sort this?

(The actual task involves fulfilling the predicate that for any list `xs` that is a prefix of another list `ys`, `pairs xs` is a prefix of `pairs ys`. I'm simply under the impression that sorting the list after producing it is probably the way to go. EDIT2: solved it by iterating the list backwards, for those wondering.)

Comment: Can you define "combined order" more rigorously? How does (a,d) compare to (b,c), for instance?

Comment: `Ord` seems insufficient for this. I'd add as another argument a quantifying function `(a,a) -> Int` that "weights" the pair, and sort according to that. Also see if you can require `Enum a` so that pairs can be converted more easily.

Comment: Isn't `sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]` sufficient for you?

Comment: @betaveros: (a,d) would be equal to (b,c). How, exactly, they're sorted doesn't matter so much as that I have a robust way of sorting them where the "lighter" elements rise to the top. If one list is abcd, and another is abcde, I have be sure that nothing with e shows up before everything from abcd, and that the order is consistent.

Comment: Sorting is the wrong way to go for your task. The right way is to think about the order in which you're iterating over the pairs.

Comment: @chi: unfortunately, this is a homework assignment with rigid requirements that are, quite frankly, _kinda_ stupid. That quantifying function is a good idea, but I have no idea how to implement it for arbitrary classes that implement ord.

Comment: @JonahStephenSwersey You write, in your comment, *(a,d) would be equal to (b,c)*. Could you explain why? What exactly do you use to compare two tuples, in the general case? It seems to me that the answer to your question hinges in this.

Comment: @interjay: I'm not sure how else to iterate over them. Like, for [1,3,6,8,9], I need to have the 1 to combine with 3 and 6, and then I need the 3 to combine with 6, and then I need the 1 again to combine with the 8, and I'm honestly not sure how to handle that case at all. Maybe iterating backwards...

Comment: If you want "nothing with e shows up before everything from abcd" and don't want to require `Enum`, might ``sortBy (\(x1,x2) (y1,y2) -> (max x1 x2, min x1 x2) `compare` (max y1 y2, min y1 y2))`` work?

Comment: Aaaand I just realized that this wouldn't solve the problem at all. Crap.

Comment: @Jubobs and suddenly I'm wondering if "Distance" is even a coherent concept when talking about a list of elements who are merely ordered, if the order between them does not imply an equal distance. If it isn't, then there is no valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Such an ordering can not exist. Not just in Haskell, but anywhere – it's mathematically impossible!

By strict-ordering tuples, you're basically creating a mapping between a two-dimensional domain and a one-dimensional one. This needs to be bijective to preserve the order axioms. Then you talk about distance, that is in this case a topological property and always works analogous to the problem of mapping the real line ℝ to the 2D-plane ℝ<sup>2</sup>.

Such bijections [exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), but it's never possible that both the mapping and its inverse are continuous (which would be necessary to preserve distances in any consistent sense).

So what you want is not achievable.